# Excel to Google Sheets Script

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-sheets

I am using a script below for excel to pull a certain row value from one sheet to another cell on a different sheet. I just want to know if this can be done with google sheets thru script and if it's possible, i will appreciate if you can walk me through the process. Here's the code I am using:

```
Sub reviewRow()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer

results = MsgBox("Do you want to View selected row?", vbYesNo, "")

If results = vbYes And Range("H13") > 1 Then
    i = Range("H13")

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D9") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D11") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D12") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H9") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("F" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H10") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("G" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H11") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("H" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K19") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("K" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K25") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("L" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K32") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("M" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K38") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("N" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K44") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("O" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K51") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("P" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K58") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("Q" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K65") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("R" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K71") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("S" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K82") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("T" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K89") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("U" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K95") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("V" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K101") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("W" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K107") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("X" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G19") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("Y" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G25") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("Z" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G32") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("AA" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G38") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("AB" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G44") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("AC" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G51") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("AD" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G58") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("AE" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G65") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("AF" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G71") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("AG" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G82") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("AH" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G89") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("AI" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G95") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("AJ" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G101") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("AK" & i)
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G107") = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("AL" & i)

Range("D9").Select

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Just like Microsoft's VBScript, Google has its own language - Apps Script. It lets you automate sheets with a Javascript-like syntax, should be easy if you know Javascript.

Tutorial and documentation from Google: https://developers.google.com/apps-script

To use it, open your Google Sheet file > **Tools** > **Script Editor...**